# Creating a value in django template form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am passing a queryset of objects to a template. How can I pass that queryset back to the view when a form is submitted?

This is what I have:

```
{% for engine in engines %}
{{engine.manufacturer}}: {{engine.name}}
{% endfor %}
...
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="engine_ids" value="{{engines}}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Export engines" name="export"/>
</form>
```

Normally `request.POST.getlist('engine_ids')` would return the string

```
[<Engine: Engine Object>, <Engine: Engine Object>, <Engine: Engine Object>, <Engine: Engine Object>, ... '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

Which is not helpful, so I did a dirty cheap hack and changed the models `__unicode__` function to return the id.

Now I get:

```
[<Engine: 2>, <Engine: 4>, <Engine: 7>, <Engine: 9>, ... '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

which is more useful because I can now generate a queryset from those IDs. However using this method, I am limited to 20 elements; anything after 20 shows as `'...(remaining elements truncated)...'`.

My question is, what are alternative ways of doing this? It would be great if I could do something like

```
{% for engine in engines %}
{{engine.manufacturer}}: {{engine.name}}
**add engine.id to a list called engine_id_list**
{% endfor %}
...
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="engine_ids" value=**engine_id_list**/>
<input type="submit" value="Export engines" name="export"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out;

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="engine_ids" value="{% for engine in engines %}{{engine.id}},{% endfor %}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Export engines" name="export"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
...
return render(request, 'template', {'engine_id_list': json.dumps([e.id for e in Engine.objects.filter(thefilter)])}
```